# How to configure motherboard to allow suspension

Tags: suspend, hibernate, acpi, bios

My computer is unable to suspend/hibernate on Ubuntu 11.10. Some people told me that probable had to do with my bios setting, that I should set my ACPI settings to S3.

The problem is that I can't find that S3 thing anywhere. I have an Asus p8p67 LE  motherboard.

The only thing I think could be related is this on "advanced->APM:

- Power on my PS/2 Keyboard : Disabled
- Power on my PS/2 Mouse : Disabled
- Restore AC Power Loss : Power Off
- Power on my PCI : Disabled
- Power on my PCIE : Disabled
- Power on my Ring : Disabled
- Power on my RTC : Disabled

Can I get suspend with that? How should I configure it?

EDIT: I explained in detail my problems in this other question (which was closed) https://askubuntu.com/questions/72009/fail-to-wake-up-after-suspend-buggy-after-hibernate

Comment: did you look at the UEFI BIOS - EZ Mode - Flexible & Easy BIOS Interface

Comment: No, I'm going to check it.

Comment: Sorry, I DID check it. It is from there from where I got the options from the original post. 

It's something like this: http://event.asus.com/2011/mb/EFI_BIOS/ 

Should I look elsewhere? I get that thing when I enter the BIOS settings.

Comment: see this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-power-options-in-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: I don't see how that question is related with mine.

Comment: Post #7 looks interesting here - any of this helps? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117643

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What does "unable to suspend mean?  What happens when you try?

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks for the link, I'll have to try that. #15 describes my symptoms step by step, by the way

Comment: It sounds like you have a buggy bios, so try updating it.

Comment: @psusi From what I read on fossfreadom link, the problem can be solved (hopefully) by a updating to a newer kernel and applying a patch. Updating the BIOS might help. 

I'll try both, though I don't know how to do either.

Comment: I've found a post explaining how to fix the problem, related to the comment by @fossfreadom

http://blog.le-vert.net/?p=24

But when I try to install the kernel I get an error saying that there isn't such a kernel available on 11.10 (kernel 3.2.1).

Is it possible to install that kernel or should I wait to Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: @Cmorales - you can download 3.2.1 from here (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2.1-precise/) - image your computer first before playing with kernels and patching just incase you get a no-booting situation. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have downloaded and I get into troubles with the nvidia and virtualbox drivers (which is something usual, from what I read). 

In addition I couldn't test if the patch worked because I tried following the instructions in the post but got some errors. 

I think I'll give up and will try to fix it in 12.04, I don't have by any means the knowledge to do it by myself now. 

Anyway, @fossfreedom, should post your comment as an answer and I'll give the bounty to you, since I think it's the most relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**your issue**

This [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117643) mentions your motherboard and an issue that is similar if not the same as yours.

It goes on to mention that a patched v3.2.1 kernel can resolve your issue.  Obviously, v3.2.1 is not the kernel in Oneiric.

**backup!**

Yes - backup!  Changing your kernel can cause black screen and non-booting scenarios.  Backup with a good image tool such as *Clonezilla*

**installing pre-built kernels**

The usual recommendation is to download the [latest ubuntu kernel](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kernel/) built with the ubuntu tool-chain - i.e. the v3.2 kernel in precise and try and install that.

You could also try the vanilla kernels built directly from the [kernel mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2.1-precise/).

**compiling your own kernel**

If these kernels do not resolve this, then you will need to compile your own kernel.

Use the link below to download the 3.2 kernel source and patch it with the ubuntu kernel config.

Then use [these instructions](http://blog.le-vert.net/?p=24) to patch your newly downloaded source with some ACPI changes.

Finally, use the remaining instructions in the link below to build your source.

---

Link Question:

1. [How to build the mainline kernel source package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89542/how-to-build-the-mainline-kernel-source-package)

Answer (score 0):

Normal BIOS settings

S0 (Working) is lit. The CPU functions in entirety; the conservation of power is on a basis of by-device.

S1 (Sleep). The CPU is stopped; The RAM is regenerated; the system functions in reduced power.

S2 (Sleep 2) The CPU does not have any power; The RAM is regenerated; the system is in lower mode of the S1.

S3 (Standby) The CPU does not have any power; The RAM regenerates at minimum; the power supply unit is in mode of reduced power. This mode is also called “Save to RAM”.

S4 (Hibernate). All is powered off, but the memory was saved like temporary file on the hard drive. This mode is called “Save to disk”.

S5 (Off) Everything is shutdown. Means you need a full reboot.

S3 is the best. It uses less power and reboots faster.

- However, "I have an Asus P8P67-M Pro motherboard which fails to suspend to ram
  under Linux yet suspends successfully under Windows 7". [read the article](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/broken-suspend-ram-asus-p8p67-motherboard-bad-bios-help-205882891.html)

I may not be a possibility at this point

Comment: As I explain in the original post, I can't find anything related to that S(x) in the BIOS settings. The article you link is interesting, I have to try updating the BIOS (though I am not sure how).

Answer (score 0):

Have your bios updated, read the instructions carefully and update the bios, (as I said read the full instructions about the update, if it doesn't provide S3 support, give up)